# Passively Buffer Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, bjt, buffer, passive-components

[image: Single pole rotary switch with op amp buffers]

I am working on a project where I would like to use a single pole rotary switch as a mode switch, but also provide power to the MCU. By providing the common on the switch with 3V, I can identify what mode the switch is in at anytime by reading pins 1-4 on the MCU.  Assuming an ideal op amp, one could simply buffer each rotary switch output and then combine the output of all buffers and connect them to the 3V input of the MCU. I would however prefer to use a passive solution to buffer each switch output rather than a active solution like the op amps. To formalize the question: Is there a way to passively buffer voltage? I don't consider myself a hardware wizard, so any suggestions are welcome.

[image: New circuit using transistors as suggested in the answers]

UPDATE 11/19/2016:  So I am trying to implement the circuit (see above) that Majenko suggested.  I am simulating the load of an MCU with the 150 ohm resistor, and I made rough guess for the value of the other resistors (100k and 1k).  The 2.2uF cap on the output is to account for the break before make nature of the rotary switch. In actual implementation, the 3V soruce will be a CR123 battery. Also note that in this circuit I only accounted for one mode.  Imagine expanding this circuit to have multiple modes each with an additional NPN BJTs that all connect to the single PNP transistor base.  Can you see anything wrong with this circuit?  Is there a good way to decrease the total current needed to drive the BJTs?

Comment: Would you consider a MOSFET too active for you?

Comment: To clarify your needs define Vin, I out, Zout other than monitor. So far it looks like a Quad Analog or a rotary switch that needs no buffering at all.

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be long before someone suggested that :).  I would consider using MOSFETs, but wanted to see if someone could offer a truly passive solution first.  The project is under serious power constraints, so I am always looking for passive ways to do things.

Comment: a "zero ohm" mechanical switch from a Voltage source does not need a buffer! What did you mean? isolation? filter? current limiter? power switch?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I would suspect isolation of the switch positions from each other whilst having a common power control that is linked to all the switches. I am just drawing a MOSFET based answer right now.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: without buffering, how can I identify which line is high, while guaranteeing they all still provide power to the same MCU pin?

Comment: I assume you want an "Off" position on the switch, otherwise there is no point in having the MCU power passing through it.  You could use a two-pole switch, one pole to control the MCU power, and the other to do the mode selection.

Comment: @PeterBennett: You are correct, I will leave one of the modes as off, and leave it as a disconnect.  Sorry that is not in the drawing.

Comment: keep in mind you must not inject signals to an MCU without power first to avoid latchup.  Your requirements are not clearly stated. Like a truth table , power spec etc,

Comment: Far from addressing the issue on the question but.. does your MCU have an ADC? Why don't you make a resistive divider, use a single ADC pin and keep the MCU powered up through other connection?

Comment: Although the picture does not show it, I intend to have one of the modes of the rotary switch be off, and leave that pin of the switch floating.  I would like to eliminate the need for an additional slider switch for power.  Your method of using an ADC pin would make good sense in the case of conserving the number of pins used.  Good point.

Comment: We have no idea what you are doing with these outputs, so any suggestions may be good or not

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 the outputs are being fed to GPIOs on the MCU, and will be set up to interrupt on edge.  Using The FET circuit below This seems to be easily achievable.

Comment: It is bad form to switch CMOS inputs the way suggested due to latchup risks of damaging the MCU . Power must ALWAYS be applied before signals. Fault can occur even if a few nanoseconds on interface before power.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Can you please offer an alternative circuit that accounts for the latchup risk?  I have seen this done in consumer electronics before so I assume there must be a way.

Comment: not until you answer my questions as the purpose of this switch and all loads. as it stands it makes no sense to switch 3V power

Comment: Please restate the question with all needed variables and I will do my best to provide you with the needed information

Comment: Input Power, Functions, Outputs, Loads

Comment: Input power: 3 volts (CR123)
Outputs: 3 v supplying up to 100 mA, as well as the mode of the rotary switch
Loads: Vdd of MCU, 3 GPIO pins open drain
Functions: Not sure what you mean on this

Comment: A low pass RC filter on the inputs to slow their rise would get around the potential problem of GPIO getting power before the rest of the chip.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Does my description above satisfy what you need to offer an alternative design?

Comment: @ThomasCameronSego Not quite. Is there a rotary position #5 for power off? otherwise why cause glitches on MCU power

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Yes, imagine a position #5 (off position) where the rotary switch is not connected to any and hence the circuit is off.

Comment: So you intend to do a PoR on each switch selection or expect it to hold? then you need a make before break rotary switch or a MOSFET MUX with deglitching and supply filtering

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I would like it to hold on when switching between modes. If I use a break before make rotary with a cap on the output, would that suffice?

Comment: yes, but good luck finding one, AFAIK they don't make these for consumers. i.e. custom,  so start to learn how to make a High side FET switch with diode and hold cap, this can sustain the voltage with 4diode OR inputs to a common emitter driving a Pch FET, then protect 4 logic inputs with 10k series R's

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: Can you give me a circuit or source so I can read more about this circuit design?  Also, see the circuit and update explanation above.  So far that is what I am working with.

Comment: @Majenko: Any thoughts on the circuit above?

Comment: Using MOSFETs reduces the current needed to drive them. The gate looks to all intents and purposes like a capacitor. Once the gate is charged there is virtually no current flowing into the gate any more. The only current flow when the system is on, besides the load, is flowing through the pullup resistor through the N channel to ground. That is why MOSFETs are used for low power systems rather than BJTs.

Comment: @ThomasCameronSego there are millions of circuit examples for high side switches . Engineers must teach themselves to learn

Comment: @Majenko:  When using MOSFETS I do have dramatically lower current but I can't support the load at 3V.  The output of the P type FET when I simulated hange around 500 mV or lower.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=high+side+switch&client=safari&hl=en-ca&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlsK3Qr7XQAhWI3YMKHRyxD8gQ_AUIBygB&biw=1024&bih=649

Comment: Then the \$R_{DSON}\$ at \$-3V_{GS}\$ of the P-FET is too high. You need a better FET.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75:  You're right - I needed to look for myself first.  Thank you for the suggestions.  I will do a little more research before I bug you all again.  One last question though:  Can we all agree that using a separate SPST switch for power, and the rotary switch for only mode switching, would require the least amount of power?

Comment: NO...FETs require no power to keep on only switching capacitance draws minor current.  YOu still haven't defined your loads. Just choose the right Logic level FET for the load.. If tiny load current use 74HC4066.. I cannot stress enough the critical importance of writing down  all input output specs for V, I , Z load before doing any design.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: I feel that I did define my loads - Input is a 3V battery, and output voltage should be 3V, up to 50 mA.  Not sure how to find Z as a complex load, but I am tempted to just say Z = V/I = 3/.05 = 60 ohm - a simple resistive load. Is there a way to define Z of an MCU experimentally?  I imagine it varies by application even with the same MCU

Answer (score 2):

A simple high-side MOSFET switch (P channel) which is switched by multiple (*wired OR*) N-channel MOSFETs, should do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCiSBk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The P-FET is normally off (R1 sees to that). When the switch is in a position to power either of the N-FETs (only 2 shown here - OFF position not shown - just add more in the same way for other positions on your switch (CircuitLab only has DPST)) then it pulls the gate of the P-FET low turning it on.

That gives you full isolation of all the switch positions from each other, low power consumption (near zero when off, and tiny amounts when on - the biggest drain is R1 - you can increase that up to 1MΩ if you like, though it will slow down the switch-off of the P-FET somewhat).

C1 is just a big reservoir to stop the MCU blacking out when you switch the switch to a new position (break-before-make = interruption in power).

When choosing your MOSFETs make sure the \$R_{DSON}\$ of the P FET is nice and low (the N FETs don't matter much) and be sure the threshold voltage (\$V_{GS}\$) of all of them is no more than around half your supply voltage (1.5V) to ensure good saturation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, as well as taking the time to scheme it for me.  Of all hardware, designing with FETS intimidates me most.  Do you have a practical source you go to for more on designing with FETS rather than the theory of operation?  Thanks again.

Comment: There are two ways of designing with FETs, just like with BJTs - easy and hard. Tbe hard way is when you are using them for linear amplification and such. That gets tricky. In this design they are simply switches. That's the easy way of working with them. There isn't much to designing with them like that. Either they are on or they are off and you don't care much about the fiddly bits in between.

Comment: Consider Logic Level FET can be used as Voltage controlled resistance with millions of options . You decide logic level control voltage, Switch resistance or RdsOn at some Vgs, high side or low side operation. All switches are inverting output so Pch are high side with active gate pull down for high side switch and Nch are Low side with pullup. Consider the source and load delta V and ESR to determine the current flow, All FETs have a transition charge capacitance (nF) that affects rise time which is inverse to RdsOn.

Comment: Why not put C1 across the N-FETs? Then you won't need as big of a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving the problem is to replace the opamps in your drawing with diodes.

The MCU will be fed with the largest voltage from the input wires.

There will be a voltage drop across the diodes so the MCU will be fed with a slightly less voltage.  If you use shottkey diode will only cause about 0.3V drop and will probably be acceptable.

As the switch is rotated the voltage to the MCU may drop when it is between between positions.  You will probably need a fairy large capacitor at the output (e.g. 100uF) so the voltage does not drop.  You will also need to ensure your MCU starts up correctly as the supply voltage comes and goes.